# ng-include use for header / footer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

New to angular.js I want to use ng-include for header and footer that are common to many pages of my site for easier update

I developped a small very basic example (basic.html) to test this but this is not working

```
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <title>Basic Angular.js</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
   </div>

    <div ng-include="'myFile.html'"> Inclusion 1</div>
    <div ng-include src="'myFile.html'"> Inclusion 2</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Myfile.html is as follow

```
<div> 
    <h1> Footer example </h1>
</div>
```

All files : basic.html, myFile.html and angular.min.js are in the same root directory (that was an issue in other posts related to ng-include errors)

While the first part of the basic.html is working fine (name input and dynamic display with angular) the ng-include is not working in both syntaxes:

```
    <div ng-include="'myFile.html'">...
```

or

```
    <div ng-include src="'myFile.html'"> ...
```

I did not miss the two consecutive quotes " and ' that were an issue in other posts related to ng-include errors.

I'm at a loss to understand what is the correct syntax or what is missing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have angular.module and angular.controller defined. ng-include won't work without them being defined. I hope it helped.

Your code should look like this, note that ng-app="myApp":

```js
(function(angular){
    // create the module and register it to angular
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    

    app.controller("maincontroller", ["$scope"]);
}(angular));
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <title>Basic Angular.js</title>
    <!--I'm using the cdn for demo purpose-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
   </div>
    <!--both of these syntax should work-->
    <div ng-include="'myFile.html'"> Inclusion 1</div>
    <div ng-include src="'myFile.html'"> Inclusion 2</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run the above snippet the myFile.html doesn't show

Comment: I created a myApp.js file containing
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    
    app.controller("maincontroller", ["$scope"]);
The myFile.html doesn't show either

Comment: You have you host it with a web server instead of open up the file directory like "file:///". It should work